# Asp.net IIS7 keep prompting user credentials for non admin users

Tags: asp.net, iis, telerik

I have an ASP.net website which is set to operate on Windows Authentication. It runs on IIS7 with windows authentication on. Every user who isn't from administrator group, Internet Explorer keep prompting for user credenials. Though when user clicks on cancel, the web site runs ok as long as user does not click on any page control.

I have a master page with telerik controls on it. This page contains AJAX Manager and ScriptManager. If user call an aspx page without master page, the credential windows doesnt appear. 
Telerik resources are registered in web.config..and as I said the website works without problem for admin group. Normal users are also from the same domain..but for them login windows keep coming...
any idea?
The website is not registerd under trusted intranet sites..but this shouldnt be a problem as otherwise admin should also get error message. 
Regards

Comment: check folder permissions ( mousedx-properties-permissions-Security )  of the folder containing the "master page" and compare them with the folder permissions of the folder cointaining aspx page without master page.

Comment: no difference...even if assign a normal user full security rights..login windows still keep poping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question as it might be helpful for others too. 
I was finaly abled to track down the issue with the help of Process Monitor. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx
It turned out that one of the CSS file didn't have enough permissions for normal users.